# Factorial Rational Limit

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits, factorial

Anything besides the squeeze theorem. Here it is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n - 1)!}{{2n}^{n}}$$

Can someone start me off?

Comment: $2 \cdot  n^n$ or $(2n)^n$?

Comment: Stirling approximation of $m!$ could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the ratio test

$$\frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n-1)!}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\sim4n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}\sim_\infty\frac4en\to\infty$$

so the given limit is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

L = $\lim_{n \to +\infty}  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. L is infinite therefore the limit of $a_n$is infinite.

Comment: That's what another answers are saying Either Improve this answer or remove it.

Comment: @DigitalBrain, please do observe that Sebi's answer was **first** , so your comment is, imo, out of order.

Comment: @Timbuc I believe MSE is not about who did it **first**, or is it?

Comment: @DigitalBrain Of course it is **if** you're telling the answerer that he's repeating things! As he was the first one to post he is **not** the one repeating things, don't you think? Anyway, I don't think *anyone* is repeating things as differences of several minutes (even up to 10 or more minutes) are pretty common in very similar answers as some people type faster than others.

Comment: @Timbuc It was about Improving

Comment: @DigitalBrain, Seriously: improving **what** if he was the first poster answering the question? That's something one can expect, sometimes (read again about the differences in times) from people posting answers that **are not** the first one.

Comment: @Timbuc But he can improve his answer right?

Comment: @DigitalBrain , that is *waayy* another thing from what your first comment conveyed. Yes, perhaps he can improve his answer, *without* any reference to other answers...though I think his answer is a hint sufficiently good to help the OP to solve his question.